How can I assign nodes to a group using migrate_source_csv?
I tried breaking things into 2 migrations were the first migration imports nodes from a CSV file and the second migration creates a group relationship.
group_content_migration.yml:
id: custom_group_content
migration_group: custom_group_content
label: 'Group content migration'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: modules/custom/custom_migrations/artifacts/node_import.csv
  ids: [id]
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: agency-group_node-basic_page
  gid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: [GID #]
  entity_id:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration:
      - node_import
    source: node_nid
  label: 'title'
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:group_content'
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - node_import

When I run this migration I get the following error message:
Error: Call to a member function label() on null in /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/group/src/Plugin/Group/RelationHandlerDefault/UiTextProvider.php on line 35 #0 /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/group/src/Plugin/Group/RelationHandler/UiTextProviderTrait.php(41): Drupal\group\Plugin\Group\RelationHandlerDefault\UiTextProvider->getRelationshipLabel(Object(Drupal\group\Entity\GroupRelationship))


As per comment #28

In group v3 the group_content was changed to group_relationship, also
it requires the plugin_id field, so your migration could look like
this:
source:
  plugin: d7_node
  node_type: oportunity
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: program-group_node-opportunity
  plugin_id:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: group_node:opportunity
  gid:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: groups_audience
    no_stub: true
    source: groups_audience
  entity_id:
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: program_node_migration
    no_stub: true
    source: nid
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:group_relationship'


Credit: mcortes19
